# Best way to snap to a value with a min and max?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a method as follows:

```
public static int snap(int x, int min, int max, int increment) {
    return 0;
}
```

x is equal to the value that you want it to snap to
min is the minimum amount
max is the maximum amount
increment is (max - min) / increment

So let's say x is 27, min is 0, max is 100, and increment is 4

Then it would return 25 because 100 / 4 = 25 so the 5 possible outcomes would be 0, 25, 50, 75, 100 and 25 is the closest to 27.

How would I write this method to return this in the most efficient way?

Comment: ok, maybe next time try to include your attempt in your question ;) 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just compare the two closest values.

```
public static int snap(int x, int min, int max, int increment) {
    int part = (max - min) / increment;
    int quotient = (x - min) / part;
    return min + (x - min - quotient * part < (quotient + 1) * part - (x - min) ? quotient * part 
            : (quotient + 1) * part);
}
```